# Automapper: Mapper ignore not working for list but working for individual objects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I have a scenario where I need to map a list of objects to other list. I created map with all properties. It doesn't work while mapping the lists. But if I map individual objects in the list then, it works fine. Here is the what I am doing:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SyncLocationModel, Location>()
            .ForMember(o => o.DistrictNumber, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

Mapping entire lists which doesn't work: (Value of DistrictNumber is getting updated here but it shouldn't as we are ignoring it in the mapping rules)

```
IEnumerable<SyncLocationModel> syncLocations = IEnumerable of SyncLocationModel
List<Location> locations = a list of Location objects
Mapper.Map(syncLocations.ToList(), locations);
```

Mapping individual object works: (DistrictNumber is ignored as expected)

```
IEnumerable<SyncLocationModel> syncLocations = IEnumerable of SyncLocationModel

foreach (var location in syncLocations)
{
     Location loc = an existing Location object
     Mapper.Map(location, loc);
}
```

Comment: When mapping to an existing collection, the destination collection is cleared first. If this is not what you want, take a look at AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: Okay but if we map individual objects then, the destination object is not cleared. Right?

Comment: Right. But if that object has collections, they are cleared. Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: Thank you @LucianBargaoanu but is there a way to map the collections without clearing it first?

Comment: Try AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I tried but I couldn't find anything on Automapper.Collection.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Automapper.Collection%20

Comment: Yes I got it right after commenting here. Installed required packages and trying it now. Thank you.